# Display category name in template

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I am trying to display a category name in a module position.

I tried:

```
<?php echo $listing['Category']['title'];?>
```

It did not work.

I followed [this link](http://www.howtojoomla.net/2008060586/how-tos/templates/how-to-display-your-page-title-in-your-template-joomla-15), but it shows the article title and I need the category one.
I'm working on Joomla 1.7.

Comment: got the answer. though sombody might benefit from it being here.
    
     <?php
     $db = &JFactory::getDBO();        
     $id = JRequest::getString('id');
     $db->setQuery('SELECT #__categories.title FROM #__content,   #__categories WHERE    
     #__content.catid = #__categories.id AND #__content.id = '.$id);   
     $category = $db->loadResult();     
     echo $category;
     ?>
    
cheers

Comment: Hi user1154641, Please post the above as an answer and mark it as solved. So that other needful people can spot it easily. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the posters comment in the OP:

```
<?php 
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $id = JRequest::getString('id'); 
    $db->setQuery('SELECT #__categories.title FROM #__content, #__categories WHERE #__content.catid = #__categories.id AND #__content.id = '.$id); 
    $category = $db->loadResult();
    echo $category; 
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Much more simple answer:

```
<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->category_title);?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Travega is really close, his code works on pages, but not on category pages.

When you use *$id = JRequest::getString('id');* on a category page (such as a category blog or list page) the id of the category is returned.  This means we need more context of the id variable, in this case the 'view'.

Here is my modified version of travega's code:

```
function getCategoryName() {
    //Modified from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928967/joomla-display-catagory-name-in-template

    $db = &JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $id = JRequest::getString('id'); 
    $view = JRequest::getString('view'); 

    if ($view == 'category') {
        $sql = "SELECT title FROM #__categories WHERE #__categories.id = $id";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT #__categories.title FROM #__content, #__categories WHERE #__content.catid = #__categories.id AND #__content.id = $id";
    }

    $db->setQuery($sql); 
    $category = $db->loadResult(); 
    return $category; 
}
```

Other relevant info:

I've only tested this on Joomla 2.5.3 on cat blog and cat list pages.  I've not tested it on   anything other than com_content component.  This means it probably won't work on weblink, contact, etc pages as you may again loose the context.